Prove $\sup_{P=(t_0,\dots,t_k)}\sum_{j=1}^k |f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} |f(t_j^n)-f(t_{j-1}^n)|$
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be right continuous $P_n=(0=t_0^n<t_1^n<\dots<t_{k_n}^n=1)$ a sequence of grids with $\max_{1\leq j\leq k_n} |t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n|\to 0 (n\to \infty)$. Show that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{P=(t_0,\dots,t_k)}\sum_{j=1}^k |f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} |f(t_j^n)-f(t_{j-1}^n)|.
\end{align*}
My idea is to show that the left supremum is greater or equal the right one and vice versa. How can I start here? Is there an "easier" direction and is my idea correct?

What is $k_n$ ?

I assume that in the sequence $(t_0,\dots,t_k)$ we have $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_k=1$. Then, clearly, the left supremum is greater or equal than the right one. On the other hand, I suppose that the function $f$ is right continuous means that for each $x\in [0,1)$ and each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each $x'\in [0,1]\cap [x,x+\delta)$ we have $|f(x)-f(x')|<\varepsilon$. Let $k$ be any natural number, $0=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_k=1$ be any real numbers, and $\varepsilon>0$ be any real number. There exists $\delta>0$ such that for each nonnegative integer $i\le k-1$ and each $x'\in [0,1]\cap [x_i,x_i+\delta)$ we have $|f(x')-f(x_i)|<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{4k}$. There exists natural $n$ such that $\max_{1\leq j\leq k_n} |t_j^n-t_{j-1}^n|<\delta$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^k |f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\le$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\varepsilon}{2k}+ \sum_{t_{i-1}<t_{j-1}^n\le t_i} |f(t_j^n)-f(t_{j-1}^n)|\le$$ $$\sum_{j=1}^{k_n} |f(t_j^n)-f(t_{j-1}^n)|+\varepsilon.$$
It follows that the left supremum is not greater than the right one. Therefore the supremums are equal.
